# unable to get product by category only getting product added lastly

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have created a query where product is getting by product sub category name or by product tags but the main problem is that I am only getting the last entered product can anyone help me out an dlet me know what and where I am doing wrong.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['step_03'])) {
    $que_01 = $_POST['que_01'];
    $que_02 = $_POST['que_02'];
    $que_03 = $_POST['que_03'];
    $subcat = array("$que_01", "$que_02", "$que_03");

    $args = array( 
        'post_type'      => 'product', 
        'posts_per_page' => 1, 
        'product_tag'    => $que_01 
    );
} else {
    if(isset($_POST['cat'])) {
        $tags = $_POST['cat'];
    }
    $args = array( 
        'post_type'      => 'product', 
        'posts_per_page' => 1, 
        'product_category'   => $tags 
    );
}
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
$product_count = $loop->post_count;
if( $product_count > 0 ) :
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
        global $post;
        echo $thePostID = $loop->post->post_title;
            }
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Hi. Third party plugins are considered off topic here.

Comment: @AndyMacaulay-Brook This question should still be answerable as its not Woo specific - ie it's just like dealing with a custom post type and taxonomy.

Comment: @TimMalone Am I getting over zealous? Having had a good read of the question, I suppose it's only the tag that gives it away!

Comment: @AndyMacaulay-Brook Yep, that's right. Ignore the tag and it's good ;) It's ok - I was making the same mistake at first too. It's a fine line!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
<?php 


if(isset($_POST['step_03'])) {
    $que_01 = $_POST['que_01'];
    $que_02 = $_POST['que_02'];
    $que_03 = $_POST['que_03'];
    $subcat = array("$que_01", "$que_02", "$que_03");

    $args = array( 
        'post_type'      => 'product', 
        'posts_per_page' => -1, 
        'product_tag'    => $que_01 
    );
} else {
    if(isset($_POST['cat'])) {
        $tags = $_POST['cat'];
    }
    $args = array( 
        'post_type'      => 'product', 
        'posts_per_page' =>  -1, 
        'product_category'   => $tags 
    );
}
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
$product_count = $loop->post_count;
if( $product_count > 0 ) :
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 
        global $post;
        echo $thePostID = $loop->post->post_title;
            }
endif;


?>
```

Comment: Your answer would be better with properly formatted code and an explanation of how it works and why it answers the question.

Comment: Yes i know that but I am using smart phone and i answered the question from anroid app. Anroid app is not having the format option or i don't know how to format that

Comment: If you are using the desktop than cou you please edit and format it for me? I an give you the answer.

Comment: iPhone app has a code button - just edited for you :-)

Comment: I am not having i phone. Anroid doesn't have the option.